# sum for X months in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a formula to get the revenue for 2 months ago. I need to get the sum of revenue for the past three months. I am very new at it and will appreciate any help! Thank you.

```
(CASE when MONTh(`Date`) = (MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())-2)

 then

 CASE when YEAR(`Date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())

 then `Revenue`

 end

 end

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tests won't work when 2 months ago is in the previous year.

Put the condition in the `WHERE` clause, and use date arithmetic to get 2 months ago.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE MONTH(Date) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
AND   YEAR(Date) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

Comment: That gave me a syntax error. Here is the solution ```(CASE when `Date` > CURRENT_DATE()-90
 

 
 
 then `Revenue`

 
 end


)```

Comment: You probably didn't put it in the proper place in the query. There's no need for CASE if you're using it in the WHEN clause.

Comment: I thought you wanted everything in the calendar month 2 months ago, not everything since then.

Answer (score 0):

If we are dealing with calendar months,

we could use `DATE_FORMAT` function to lop off the day portion, an expression like this:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(t.`date`,'%Y-%m-01')
```

and then we can compare that expression to other date values.

It's not entirely clear what result we are attempting to achieve. If the goal is to get a total revenue for 3 months ago and 2 months ago, we could do conditional aggregation.

Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE DATE_FORMAT(t.`date`,'%Y-%m-01')
              WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -3 MONTH
              THEN t.`revenue`
              ELSE NULL
            END
       ) AS revenue_3_months_ago
     , SUM( CASE DATE_FORMAT(t.`date`,'%Y-%m-01')
              WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -2 MONTH
              THEN t.`revenue`
              ELSE NULL
            END
       ) AS revenue_2_months_ago
     , SUM( CASE
              WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.`date`,'%Y-%m-01')
                   >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -3 MONTH
               AND DATE_FORMAT(t.`date`,'%Y-%m-01')
                   <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL  0 MONTH
              THEN t.`revenue`
              ELSE NULL
            END
       ) AS revenue_past_3_months
  FROM t
```

---

NOTE:  we can test expressions in SELECT statement, before we incorporate them in more complex SQL

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -3 MONTH  AS `n3`
     , DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -1 MONTH  AS `n1` 
     , DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL  0 MONTH  AS `n0`
```

Answer (score 0):

`TIMESTAMPDIFF()` does exactly what you want.  It counts the number of month boundaries between two dates, so:

```
(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, date, curdate()) = 2
      THEN `Revenue`

 END)
```

Comment: It gave me an error: Invalid Formula: This calculation is using a nonexistent function.